# getting specific number of rows is not working codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying this code to get the specific set of rows but what happens is that it gets the last row (52nd row) :

```
 public  function getCards ($num){
        $query = $this->db->get('cards', 0 , 12);
         switch ($num){
             case 1 : $query = $this->db->get('cards', 0 , 12);
             case 2 :  $query = $this->db->get('cards', 13, 25);
             case 3:  $query = $this->db->get('cards', 26, 38);
             case 4 :  $query = $this->db->get('cards', 39,51);
         }
         $i=0;
          foreach ($query->result() as $row ) :
             $cards[$i]=$row->cards;
             $i++;

          endforeach;

          return $cards;
     }
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: Under what circumstances does it return the last row? Does it always return the last row or only when you call `getCards` with a particular number? Please provide a fuller context.

Comment: in case 1 , 2 ,3 and 4 returns the last row otherwise it returns the whole rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, as it appears you are using the second and third parameters as upper and lower bounds instead of limit and offset. be sure you are looking into the documentation provided by [codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html):

> The second and third parameters enable you to set a limit and offset clause:
>
> `$query = $this->db->get('mytable', 10, 20);`

For example:
Case (2) currently is starting at **row 25** (offset) and getting the **next 13** (limit) records.

So your query just needs to be adjusted for these parameters instead of using them as upper and lower bounds.

Comment: case 1 : $query = $this->db->get('cards', 13 , 1); I have edit it to be like this it should now return the 13 row starting from first row but what happens is that it returns the last 13 row